# Naming collision in react native app start

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm using the out-of-the box react native framework to try to build a new app.

i used the following commands ind CMD (Windows 10).

node -v:
v8.12.0

npm -v:
6.4.1

mkdir react-native-workspace

cd react-native-workspace

npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app Exercise2

cd Exercise2

npm start

> > ERROR 12:42 (node:15564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:   Duplicate module
> >     name: my-new-project   Paths:
> >     C:\Users\wp_99\Dokumenter\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\package.json
> >     collides with
> >     C:\Users\wp_99\Documents\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\package.json
>
> This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same
>   name across two different files.
>       at setModule (C:\Users\wp_99\Documents\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:462:17)
>       at workerReply (C:\Users\wp_99\Documents\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:512:9)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) ERROR 12:42 (node:15564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
>   an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
>   which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:15564)
>   [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the metro-bundler. You should create rn-cli.config.js and add this configuration to it:
For react-native>=0.57

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver:{
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /nodejs-assets\/.*/,
      /android\/.*/,
      /ios\/.*/
    ])
  },
};
```

react-native < 0.57

```
const blacklist = require('metro/src/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE: function() {
    return blacklist([
      /nodejs-assets\/.*/,
      /android\/.*/,
      /ios\/.*/
    ]);
  },
};
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-react-native/tree/ed727edea17e8a9e1a85cef3413becc83b8a0328#duplicate-module-name).

Comment: i have done the following: 

C:\Users\wp_99\Dokumenter\react-native-workspace\Exercise2>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1

so i added "const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver:{
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /nodejs-assets\/.*/,
      /android\/.*/,
      /ios\/.*/
    ])
  },
};  

in a file placed in root called "rn-cli.config.js"

it dosen't work it gives this message:

Comment: This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at setModule (C:\Users\wp_99\Documents\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:462:17)
    at workerReply (C:\Users\wp_99\Documents\react-native-workspace\Exercise2\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:512:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following to rn-cli.config.js

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([
            /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
        ])
    },
};
```