# jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: react-native when attempting to generate .ipa

Tags: xcode, react-native, ipa

I need to generate an `.ipa` of the different targets my project has, but whether I do it in command line or via Xcode I continue to get the following error:

```
jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision: react-native
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/package.json
    * <rootDir>/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json

Failed to construct transformer:  { Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (/Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:691:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  mockPath1: 'node_modules/react-native/package.json',
  mockPath2:
   'ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json' }
```

I have already tried creating the `rn-cli.config.js` file like this:

```
const blacklist = require("metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist");

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/nodejs-assets\/.*/, /android\/.*/, /ios\/.*/])
  }
};
```

or this:

```
const blacklist = require("metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist");

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/])
  }
};
```

Neither of which has worked for me. I do also have a `metro.config.js`:

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

The steps here did not work for me:

[How to fix React Native error "jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408307/how-to-fix-react-native-error-jest-haste-map-haste-module-naming-collision)

[Naming collision in react native app start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392560/naming-collision-in-react-native-app-start)

[Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108310/error-jest-haste-map-haste-module-naming-collision)

I have tried running an `rm -rf ios/build` but eventually when it gets recreated the error returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked was running the following command:

```
rm ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring solution, actually, my address is different from yours but surely the package.json in the ios build should be deleted. I upvote both of your posts, and also I will post my general solution. furthermore, I will upvote some others your posts.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because i had duplicate node_module folder by the name node_module_bak created by a script check that you have the same.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this error happens just for a collision occurring. I don't know why it happens but obviously its a collision between these two:

1. `<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/package.json`
2. `<rootDir>/ios/build/[MY_BUILD_NAME]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[MY_BUILD_NAME].app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json`

It is so clear to me that the second one is useless and the root of collision. so when I removed it everything became ok and everything worked well again. so use these command:

```
$ cd [YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_PATH]
$ rm ios/build/[MY_BUILD_NAME]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[MY_BUILD_NAME].app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json
```

Comment: worked for me. Need to add script to Podfile to avoid remove it every time by hand after pod install

Answer (score 0):

If you have init a new project in same main directory try to move it out and keep them in different places